# Loading a file on .NET server

Tags: asp.net, .net

I know that when you're using ASP.NET, you can use runat="server" to get relative pathing to work. Is there a way I can accomplish that with a regular string path? My call looks like this

```
userConfig.Load("~\\App_Data\\userConfigDefault.xml");
```

I get the error code of

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\App_Data\userConfigDefault.xml'.
```

I'd the xml file to be in my solution, but I also can't hard code its location because this application is going to be portable. I need to figure out how to relative path in my C# code.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Edit:
The file path for the XML file I'm trying to read is actually the App_Data folder in the project solution. Rion's first solution pointed me to my user\AppData\Roaming. I am not a picky man. Pointing to any folder in my Visual Studio solution will solve my problem.

Comment: Are you looking for `userConfig.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\userConfigDefault.xml"))`?

Comment: I couldn't get Server to work, but I found a work around. Thank you!
`var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\userConfigDefault.xml");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally if you are going to access a file from your App_Data directory, you should consider using the `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` property as seen below :

```
// This will resolve the appropriate path for your App_Data directory
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),"userConfigDefault.xml");
```

Alternatively, [`Server.MapPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx) will also work and should accept a relative path that points to the appropriate directory :

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"userConfigDefault.xml");
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to use the `App_Data` folder of the web site, not the machine.

Comment: If that's the case, then the `Server.MapPath()` approach might be the most appropriate way to handle that, which I have included as well. Thanks for pointing that out.